# Find binary tree height

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to write a function to get the height of a binary tree. When I print the value of the `maxi` the value is what I expect but when the function returns the value, the value is always 0. Can someone tell what I am doing wrong here?

```
int treeHeight(tree *p)
{
    static int maxi=0;
    static int i=0;
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        return maxi;
    }
    else
    {
        if(p->left!=NULL||p->right!=NULL)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            if(maxi<i)
            {
                maxi=i;
            }
        }
        treeHeight(p->left);
        treeHeight(p->right);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you didn't have warnings disabled, the compiler would have told you what you forgot.

Answer (score 9):

Your `treeHeight` function should look like the following:

```
int treeHeight(tree *p)
{
   if (p == NULL)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   int left = treeHeight(p->left);
   int right = treeHeight(p->right); 

   return 1 + std::max(left, right);
}
```

Why do you need to static variables `i` and `maxi` there? You don't need those variables there to find out the height of a binary tree.

Comment: There's a std::max() function that would be useful here. And there's a `const` keyword that should be sprinkled in. Other than that, much clearer code!

Comment: If there is only one node in the tree then the height of the tree should be 0. But your code would return 1.

Comment: @user2105632 You are right in this case I guess, from the NIST definition, a tree with single node has height 0, a simple change is to return -1 when `p ==NULL`